# spark SQL to perform simple arithmetic with constant

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying do arithmetic operation with two operands: `constant literal` and `Column`. Is there an approach other than `withColumn`?

Comment: what's the problem with withColumn? You could also do it in a select-statement

Comment: how to do it with select-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `df` be a dataframe:

```
+---+
|  i|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

then you can use select to add the results:

```
import org.apache spark.sql.functions.lit 

df
.select($"i",($"i" + lit(1)).as("j"))
.show

+---+---+
|  i|  j|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael. As a follow-up question, I was able to do this: `TABLE_2_0.select(($"exchr"/1).as("j")).show`. 

but when i do `TABLE_2_0.select((1/$"exchr").as("j")).show`, 

I get: `<console>:51: error: overloaded method value / with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName)`

Comment: @sandeep you need to to do `TABLE_2_0.select((lit(1)/$"exchr").as("j"))` in this case (`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit`)